# How to make all browsers on my Windows unable to display a certain language

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, language, input-languages

I have windows desktop.

I have Chrome (which I use the most often), Edge, Explorer, Firefox and so on.

I tried deleting some fonts files but that didn't work. Maybe deleting fonts is not the solution or I deleted wrong font.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't do this.

Comment: I agree. Modern websites supply their own fonts; and anyway, a font is not specific for a language.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode fonts have glyphs for your language of choice plus a large subset of the other languages that might be used in a particular region plus symbols. So you will have to attempt replacing all the fonts on your system with identical fonts having only the limited subset you wish to display i.e. try to go back to the good old days of DOS and codepages and 255 byte character sets.

You can use Character Map to show you what glyphs are available in each font used on your system, but then there are two webfont systems that will come into play that you have to block from loading as well.